# What is the minimum iPhone model which Apple will let me to compile and submit to AppStore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store, submit

For sometime, i am developing for iOS in a company.

I will quit and go iOS freelancing.
I need to buy an iPhone.

I want to buy a model as old as i could, for both performance testing on a crappy configuration and for budget issues.

I am wondering about the minimum iPhone model i could buy which Apple will let me compile both 32bit/64bit and submit to Appstore.

And may you also make a guess for how long Apple will let me use it before having to buy a newer model.

Will an iPhone5 ModelA1429 do the job which i am considering to buy at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

An iPhone 3Gs, running iOS 6.x, is the currently (as of October of 2015) the oldest device that can be used for testing apps builds that can be submitted to Apple's iOS App store.  (A 1st generation iPad, running iOS 5.1.1 can't run exactly the same build as you are required to submit.)

Xcode 7.x currently allows setting the Deployment Target as low as iOS 6.0.

Apple still allows submission of apps with a Deployment Target of 6.x.  However you currently must compile the app with the SDK for iOS 8 or later and include arm64 support in the build to meet current App store submission requirements; and you also should test your app for compatibility with iOS 6.x thru iOS 9 (or whatever is the latest iOS release) if your Deployment target is set to iOS 6.x.

To test the actual 64-bit code in arm64 builds, the oldest device that can be used is the iPhone 5s.  To test under iOS 9, the oldest device that can be used is an iPhone 4s.